# unorder_map<float, short> Why does this work?

Tags: hash, hashtable, unordered-map

I am using an `unordered_map<float, unsigned short>` to implement a hash table in C++.

I know that using floats as keys to a hash table is a **bad** idea under most circumstances because comparing them is error-prone.  However, under these circumstances, I am reading the floats in from large files and their precision is known and constant.

However, I would like to know the details of how `unordered_map` is hashing my floats in order to estimate collision frequency.  I am not overriding the default hash implementation when I create the `unordered_map`. According to the documentation, the default hash function is `std::hash<Key>`.  Which in my case is `std::hash<float>`.  However, when I look at the `std::hash` documentation, it is only defined for "template arguments of type `char*`, `const char*`, `crope`, `wrope`, and the built-in integral types".

Does anyone know what function is being called to hash the values as I add them to the unordered_map?

`unordered_map` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982522.aspx

`std::hash` - http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash.html#1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the C++11 standard, `float` is supported for `std::hash` as well. The actual hash function is implementation dependent, so even if you can figure out collision frequency for your current compiler a newer version or a different compiler may implement a different hash function. Here is the full list of `std::hash` specializations:

```
template <> struct hash<bool>;
template <> struct hash<char>;
template <> struct hash<signed char>;
template <> struct hash<unsigned char>;
template <> struct hash<char16_t>;
template <> struct hash<char32_t>;
template <> struct hash<wchar_t>;
template <> struct hash<short>;
template <> struct hash<unsigned short>;
template <> struct hash<int>;
template <> struct hash<unsigned int>;
template <> struct hash<long>;
template <> struct hash<unsigned long>;
template <> struct hash<long long>;
template <> struct hash<unsigned long long>;
template <> struct hash<float>;
template <> struct hash<double>;
template <> struct hash<long double>;
template <class T> struct hash<T*>;
```

Comment: @JHowIX: It didn't _exist_ before C++11.