# Efficiently moving contents of std::unordered_set to std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, copy

In my code I have a `std::unordered_set` and I need to move the data into a `std::vector`. I'm using the `std::unordered_set` while getting the data to ensure only unique values are stored prior to converting to a `std::vector`. My question is how do I move the contents to the `std::vector` the most efficiently? I don't need the `std::unordered_set` after the data is moved. I currently have the following:

```
std::copy(set.begin(), set.end(), std::back_inserter(vector));
```

Comment: Surely `std::vector::reserve` would help (if you're not doing that already).

Comment: What, exactly, is your data?

Comment: It's numeric values. `std::vector<double>`

Comment: For `double`, copy is as efficient as move, but you should reserve as LogicStuff recommends.  Separately, if in your case it takes time for the data to arrive (e.g. over the network, from a huge file doing async I/O etc) and you don't actually need the vector sorted, you could check whether it's the first time you've seen a value as you attempt insertion to the set, and if so also insert to the vector so it's ready to use as soon as the last input's received (though this works best if you know the number of elements to reserve beforehand).

Comment: Do you consider two double same if they are "nearly equal"? 
The default hashing maybe not enough in some cases.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943817/does-stdhash-guarantee-equal-hashes-for-equal-floating-point-numbers

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Before C++17, the best you can do is:

```
vector.insert(vector.end(), set.begin(), set.end());
```

The `set`'s elements are `const`, so you can't move from them - moving is just copying.

---

After C++17, we get [`extract()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/extract):

```
vector.reserve(set.size());
for (auto it = set.begin(); it != set.end(); ) {
    vector.push_back(std::move(set.extract(it++).value()));
}
```

Although given your comment that your data is `double`s, this wouldn't matter.

Comment: Is `set.extract(it++)` really okay?  What if the increment happens after the `extract` call invalidates the iterator?

Comment: @Dan It can't. All of `it++` has to happen *before* the function is evaluated.

Comment: I think before C++17 should also have a reserve

Comment: @KrvPerera No, it's fine as-is.

Comment: @Barry Thanks barry I found the answer by reading some SO answers. So reserve happens upfront because they are not input iterators. I should have done more research.

Comment: `set.extract` would rebalance the tree; is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Why not use a simple `for(auto& element : set){ vector.push_back(std::move(element));}` ?

Comment: @BRabbit27 as mentioned, a set only exposes const access to the elements. Moving = copying.

Comment: It there any difference between your answer and 
`for (auto it = set.begin(); it != set.end(); it++) {
vector.push_back(std::move(set.extract(it).value()));
}` ? Since extract keeps the order, moving iterator should be fine.

Comment: @Michaël, I believe there is no rebalance for `std::set` per https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/extract "Extracting a node invalidates only the iterators to the extracted element, and preserves the relative order of the elements that are not erased. "