# Moving elements out of an unordered_set

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an `unordered_set<string>`, and I want to consume (i.e. move from) each element in this set and do something with it. Syntactically, I see a few ways of doing this:

```cpp
unordered_set<string> s = ...;

// 1
for (auto& x : s) {
  auto x2 = std::move(x);
  do_something(x2);
}

// 2
auto first = std::make_move_iterator(s.begin());
auto last = std::make_move_iterator(s.end());
while (first != last) {
  auto x2 = *first++;
  do_something(x2);
}

// 3
while (!s.empty()) {
  auto it = s.begin();
  auto x2 = std::move(*it);
  s.erase(it);
  do_something(x2);
}
```

However, all of them give me the concern that I'm modifying the container as I iterate over it. I suspect at least 2 is safe though, because this is valid:

```cpp
unordered_set<string> s;
vector<string> v;
v.insert(std::make_move_iterator(s.begin()),
         std::make_move_iterator(s.end()));
```

I'm not positive whether any of 1-3 is defined to be safe/valid at all. If so, where can I find the supporting evidence? If not, what are some safe ways to do what I want?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Ah, so it seems since C++17 `extract` is the way, and before C++17 there isn't any way to do it?

Comment: Exactly correct.

Comment: @ZizhengTai You wish to move out the entire `unordered_set`? And then have the set be destroyed?

Comment: @orlp That's another option. How can I do it? (I was hoping I can move each element out individually to avoid having to allocate another container, but seems that's not possible until C++17.)

Comment: @orlp Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/42519996/3234803 I don't think it's possible?

Comment: you don’t need `extract` why not just use `unordered_set::erase()` ? And remove the first element at each iteration. You may also use range loop with it (like `for (auto& elem : s) { s::erase(s.begin())}`

Comment: @ZizhengTai Looks like it...

Comment: @Iman But you can't get an rvalue reference out of the set. It has no interface for doing so.

Comment: @ZizhengTai right! I just learned what you are asking 

Comment: Well, you can’t `move` it all elements of `unordered_set` are `const` so none of your three codes may work.

Comment: `std::erase` or `set::erase` will return you the iterator to the next one and delete the specified one.

Comment: @ArmaniStyles Yes, but it doesn't give you a way to move from the erased element.