# Extracting from set/unordered_set while using iterators

Tags: c++, c++17

I just learned about the [`extract`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/extract) function added to `std::set`/`std::unordered_set` in C++17. I know this is valid:

```cpp
while (!my_set.empty()) {
  auto node_handle = my_set.extract(my_set.begin());
  auto elem = std::move(node_handle.value());
}
```

But is the following safe? (From https://stackoverflow.com/a/42519996/3234803)

```cpp
for (auto it = my_set.begin(); it != my_set.end(); ) {
  auto node_handle = my_set.extract(it++);
  auto elem = std::move(node_handle.value());
}
```

I know `extract` invalidates the iterator passed to it, so `extract(it++)` saves the next iterator into `it` before `it` gets invalidated. But is it guaranteeed that `extract` doesn't invalidated other iterators?

Comment: @parktomatomi the link says "All Associative Containers: The extract members invalidate only iterators to the removed element; pointers and references to the removed element remain valid [26.2.6/10]"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterator invalidation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules)

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili misread that, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But is it guaranteeed that extract doesn't invalidated other iterators?

Yes. Extract is guaranteed to not invalidate other iterators. Both loops are safe.